# How do I get the bounding box of a mapboxgl.GeoJSONSource object?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm setting up a Mapbox GL JS map like this:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.my_token';
var cityBoundaries   = new mapboxgl.GeoJSONSource({ data: 'http://domain.com/city_name.geojson' } );
var map              = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v8',
  center: [cityLongitude,cityLatitude],
  zoom: 13
});
```

Then I'm loading that GeoJSON data onto the map after it loads like this:

```
map.on('style.load', function(){
  map.addSource('city', cityBoundaries);
  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'city',
    'type': 'line',
    'source': 'city',
    'paint': {
      'line-color': 'blue',
      'line-width': 3
    }
  });
});
```

At this point, I have a map that's centered at the location I specified in `new mapboxgl.Map`, and it's at zoom level 13. So, only a piece of the GeoJSON data is visible on the map. I'd like to re-center and re-zoom the map so that the entire GeoJSON data is visible.

In Mapbox JS, I would do this by loading the GeoJSON data into a `featureLayer` and then fitting the map to its bounds with:

```
map.fitBounds(featureLayer.getBounds());
```

The [fitBounds documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map.fitBounds) for Mapbox GL JS indicates that it wants the bounds in the format of `[[minLng, minLat], [maxLng, maxLat]]`.

Is there a way to determine the mix/max latitude & longitude values of this GeoJSON layer?

Answer (score 10):

Based on the 'Obtaining a bounding box' section of [this post](http://mikefowler.me/2014/06/10/drawing-geojson-in-a-canvas/), I've come up with this process...

```
map.on('style.load', function(){
  $.getJSON('http://citystrides.dev/city_name.geojson', function(response){
    var boundingBox = getBoundingBox(response);
    var cityBoundary = new mapboxgl.GeoJSONSource({ data: response } );

    map.addSource('city', cityBoundary);
    map.addLayer({
      'id': 'city',
      'type': 'line',
      'source': 'city',
      'paint': {
        'line-color': 'blue',
        'line-width': 3
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds([[boundingBox.xMin, boundingBox.yMin], [boundingBox.xMax, boundingBox.yMax]]);
  })
});

function getBoundingBox(data) {
  var bounds = {}, coords, point, latitude, longitude;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
    coords = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates;

    for (var j = 0; j < coords.length; j++) {
      longitude = coords[j][0];
      latitude = coords[j][1];
      bounds.xMin = bounds.xMin < longitude ? bounds.xMin : longitude;
      bounds.xMax = bounds.xMax > longitude ? bounds.xMax : longitude;
      bounds.yMin = bounds.yMin < latitude ? bounds.yMin : latitude;
      bounds.yMax = bounds.yMax > latitude ? bounds.yMax : latitude;
    }
  }

  return bounds;
}
```

Here's a walkthrough of what the code is doing, for anyone out there who needs a detailed explanation:

- `map.on('style.load', function(){`

  - When the map loads, let's do the stuff in this function.
- `$.getJSON('http://citystrides.dev/city_name.geojson', function(response){`

  - Get the city's GeoJSON data. This is an asynchronous call, so we have to put the all the code that uses this data (the `response`) inside this function.
- `var boundingBox = getBoundingBox(response);`

  - Get the bounding box of this GeoJSON data. This is calling the `, function(){` that appears after the 'map on style load' block.
- `var cityBoundary = new mapboxgl.GeoJSONSource({ data: response } );`

  - Build Mapbox's GeoJSON data.
- `map.addSource('city', cityBoundary);`

  - Add the source to Mapbox.
- `map.addLayer({`

  - Add the layer to Mapbox.
- `map.fitBounds([[boundingBox.xMin, boundingBox.yMin], [boundingBox.xMax, boundingBox.yMax]]);`

  - Adjust the map to fix the GeoJSON data into view.
- `function getBoundingBox(data) {`

  - This function iterates over the returned GeoJSON data, finding the minimum and maximum latitude and longitude values.

---

One thing to note in the `getBoundingBox` function is this line:

```
coords = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
```

In the original post, linked above, this line was written as `coords = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0];` because their data for the list of coordinates was an array of arrays. My data isn't formatted that way, so I had to drop the `[0]`. If you try this code & it blows up, that might be the reason.

Comment: This function should probably specify that it only works for polygons. Like you said, it won't work for other geometries that don't have the same structure such as a Point, MultiPoint, and LineStrings.

Comment: It's not for Polygons. Only for MultiPoints, and it works pretty good for them.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `turf.js` library. It has a `bbox` function:

```
const bbox = turf.bbox(foo);
```

https://turfjs.org/docs/#bbox

Answer (score 2):

I use the turf-extent library, which is maintained by the Mapbox bunch anyhow. https://www.npmjs.com/package/turf-extent is the node module link. 
In your code you simply import(ES6) or require as so:

```
ES6/Webpack: import extent from 'turf-extent';
Via script tag: `<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/turf/v2.0.2/turf.min.js'></script>`
```

Then feed your response to the function, for example:

```
ES6/Webpack: let orgBbox = extent(response);
Normal: var orgBbox = turf.extent(geojson);
```

Then you can use the array values to set your map center:

```
center: [orgBbox[0], orgBbox[1]]
```

Or as you want, to fit bounds:

```
map.fitBounds(orgBbox, {padding: 20});
```

Here is an example using the turf.min.js in a regular html  tag in case you are not using webpack or browser:
https://bl.ocks.org/danswick/83a8ddff7fb9193176a975a02a896792

Happy coding and mapping!

Answer (score 2):

Based on James Chevalier's answer. For polygon/multipolygon tilesets that are assigend to a map in Mapbox Studio I am using this to get the bounding box:

```
getPolygonBoundingBox: function(feature) {
    // bounds [xMin, yMin][xMax, yMax]
    var bounds = [[], []];
    var polygon;
    var latitude;
    var longitude;

    for (var i = 0; i < feature.geometry.coordinates.length; i++) {
        if (feature.geometry.coordinates.length === 1) {
            // Polygon coordinates[0][nodes]
            polygon = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];
        } else {
            // Polygon coordinates[poly][0][nodes]
            polygon = feature.geometry.coordinates[i][0];
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < polygon.length; j++) {
            longitude = polygon[j][0];
            latitude = polygon[j][1];

            bounds[0][0] = bounds[0][0] < longitude ? bounds[0][0] : longitude;
            bounds[1][0] = bounds[1][0] > longitude ? bounds[1][0] : longitude;
            bounds[0][1] = bounds[0][1] < latitude ? bounds[0][1] : latitude;
            bounds[1][1] = bounds[1][1] > latitude ? bounds[1][1] : latitude;
        }
    }

    return bounds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first use the `@turf/turf` package:

```
import * as turf from '@turf/turf'
```

then construct a bbox via your JSON source feature (in this case a line string):

```
const locationCoords = locations.map(({ latitude, longitude }) => [
    longitude,
    latitude,
])


const line = turf.lineString(locationCoords)
const bbox = turf.bbox(line) as LngLatBoundsLike

newMap.fitBounds(bbox)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on James Chevalier's AND tobias47n9e answer.

I have extended the answers with a recursive approach to be able to process all types of polygons and multipolygons. With the answer of tobias47n9e I got partly no results, because the different structures of the polygons were not addressed.

```
function getPolygonBoundingBox(arr, bounds = [[], []]) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i][0][0])){
      bounds = getPolygonBoundingBox(arr[i], bounds);
    } else {
      polygon = arr[i];
      for (var j = 0; j < polygon.length; j++) {
        longitude = polygon[j][0];
        latitude = polygon[j][1];
        bounds[0][0] = bounds[0][0] < longitude ? bounds[0][0] : longitude;
        bounds[1][0] = bounds[1][0] > longitude ? bounds[1][0] : longitude;
        bounds[0][1] = bounds[0][1] < latitude ? bounds[0][1] : latitude;
        bounds[1][1] = bounds[1][1] > latitude ? bounds[1][1] : latitude;
      }
    }
  }
  return bounds;
 }
 
 
getPolygonBoundingBox(feature.geometry.coordinates);
```