# Mapbox GL JS: zoom to filtered polygon?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using Mapbox GL JS to display a polygon layer. I would to allow the user to choose a name from a dropdown, and then highlight and zoom to the matching polygon.

I already know how to highlight the matching polygon using `map.setFilter`, but I don't know how to zoom to the bounds of the matching polygon. This is my current code:

```
map.addLayer({
    'id': 'polygon_hover',
    'source': 'mysource',
    'source-layer': 'mylayer',
    'type': 'fill',
    'paint': {
        'fill-color': 'red',
        "fill-opacity": 0.6
    },
    "filter": ["==", 'CUSTNAME', ""]
});
// Get details from dropdown
custname.on("change", function(e) {
    // get details of name from select event
    map.setFilter('polygon_hover', ["==", 'CUSTNAME', name]);
    // Get bounds of filtered polygon somehow?
    // var bounds = ??;
    // map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

I have examined the [Mapbox example of zooming to bounds](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/zoomto-linestring/), but it assumes that you already know what the bounds are.

Is there any way it's possible to get the bounds of the polygon matching a map filter in Mapbox?

Comment: Wonder what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 6):

I've the following code to fitBounds to Polygon center coords:

```
var coordinates = f.geometry.coordinates[0];
var bounds = coordinates.reduce(function (bounds, coord) {
    return bounds.extend(coord);
}, new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(coordinates[0], coordinates[0]));

map.fitBounds(bounds, {
    padding: 20
});
```

Where f is one Feature.

Comment: This does not first get the feature nor its bounds or geometries

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to your problem. [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/download.html) has a [polygon](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polygon) Class which takes an Array of polygon coordinates and has a function called `getBounds()` that returns south west and north east bounds. However, Leaflet doesn't follow the convention of **LngLat**, its format is **LatLng**. Therefore, you have to switch it. I took an example out from Mapbox [Show drawn polygon area](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-draw/), and added exactly what you're looking for.

```
var polygon = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates;
var fit = new L.Polygon(polygon).getBounds();
var southWest = new mapboxgl.LngLat(fit['_southWest']['lat'], fit['_southWest']['lng']);
var northEast = new mapboxgl.LngLat(fit['_northEast']['lat'], fit['_northEast']['lng']);
var center = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(southWest, northEast).getCenter();
// map.flyTo({center: center, zoom: 10});
map.fitBounds(new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(southWest, northEast));
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I get the value of `data.features[0].geometry.coordinates` though? All I have is the `name` value from the select event.

Comment: @Richard in your code that you post above, it should be `e.features`...

Comment: This is a response for leaflet, not GL JS as specific in OP

Answer (score 2):

I see that the question is still relevant - I solved it making a separate request to the database containing all points of a given polygon and building bounds `[[minLng, minLat], [maxLng, maxLat]]`.
All attempts to address geometry of already rendered or source features didn't work for me - most probably because Mapbox doesn't keep initial geoJSON in the tiles.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved it.

I have extended different answers from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35685551/10331580 with a recursive approach to be able to process all types of polygons and multipolygons. With the answer of tobias47n9e I got partly no results, because the different structures of the polygons were not addressed. I didn't want to import Leaflet or Turf!

```js
function getPolygonBoundingBox(arr, bounds = [[], []]) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i][0][0])){
      bounds = getPolygonBoundingBox(arr[i], bounds);
    } else {
      polygon = arr[i];
      for (var j = 0; j < polygon.length; j++) {
        longitude = polygon[j][0];
        latitude = polygon[j][1];
        bounds[0][0] = bounds[0][0] < longitude ? bounds[0][0] : longitude;
        bounds[1][0] = bounds[1][0] > longitude ? bounds[1][0] : longitude;
        bounds[0][1] = bounds[0][1] < latitude ? bounds[0][1] : latitude;
        bounds[1][1] = bounds[1][1] > latitude ? bounds[1][1] : latitude;
      }
    }
  }
  return bounds;
}


getPolygonBoundingBox(feature.geometry.coordinates);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar question with an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35685551/10331580

I ported the answer there over to typescript for myself.

```
getBoundingBox(feature: mapboxgl.MapboxGeoJSONFeature): mapboxgl.LngLatBoundsLike | undefined {
  let coordinates = (feature.geometry as any).coordinates[0];
  let bounds: {
    xMin?: number,
    xMax?: number,
    yMin?: number,
    yMax?: number
  } = {}

  for (let i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
    let longitude = coordinates[i][0];
    let latitude = coordinates[i][1];
    if (bounds.xMin && bounds.xMax && bounds.yMin && bounds.yMax) {
      bounds.xMin = bounds.xMin < longitude ? bounds.xMin : longitude
      bounds.xMax = bounds.xMax > longitude ? bounds.xMax : longitude;
      bounds.yMin = bounds.yMin < latitude ? bounds.yMin : latitude;
      bounds.yMax = bounds.yMax > latitude ? bounds.yMax : latitude;
    } else {
      bounds.xMin = longitude
      bounds.xMax = longitude
      bounds.yMin = latitude
      bounds.yMax = latitude
    }
  }
  if (bounds.xMin && bounds.xMax && bounds.yMin && bounds.yMax) {
    return new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(
      new mapboxgl.LngLat(bounds.xMin, bounds.yMin),
      new mapboxgl.LngLat(bounds.xMax, bounds.yMax)
    )
  }
  return undefined;
}

fitToPolygon(feature: mapboxgl.MapboxGeoJSONFeature) {
  let bounds = this.getBoundingBox(feature)
  if (bounds) {
    this.map.fitBounds(bounds, {
      padding: 20
    })
  }
}
```